# how to filtered a bunch of non-labeled article data using my weak-model by its similarity of word in python?

Tags: python, filter, scikit-learn, deep-learning, nlp

I have 9000 samples of non-labeled articles, i want to label it to be binary class (0 and 1)

Additionally, i have 500 labeled samples  belonging to the positive class (label=1) and no samples for the negative class label=0.

I know it's impossible to label 9000 samples with 0 and 1 using a model trained only on the 500 positive samples.

So i would like to implement a "similarity" approach to classify the 9000 samples on the base of their "word similarity" with the 500 positive samples. To extract the similar data from the 9000 data, so i can label it with 1. so the rest of data from the 9000 dataset can be labeled as 0 class.

so the question, is it possible to filtered it? if so, how can i filtered it with the similarity of word with python?

thank you for your answer, i hope i have the solution :)

Comment: It depends on what you consider to be 'similar' data. You could build a trie of the labeled data, and then compare your unlabled data against it, marking all data that is 'different enough' from the trie data as 0.

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is possible. You can use doc2vec (I suggest gensim library for python) to build a vector space for the words in your 500 positive documents. Using that representation it is possible to query the similarity between a new samples (a sample from you 9000 samples) and your corpora dataset (500 samples). If you consider the similarity "similar enough" you can label it as 1.

For a nice tutorial and code refer to: 
https://markroxor.github.io/gensim/static/notebooks/doc2vec-IMDB.html

you can skip the "Predictive Evaluation Methods"
probably the most interesting section for you is: "Do close documents seem more related than distant ones?"

EDIT: answer to the comment. Yes I used the code some time ago (I don't remember too well if I had errors). The implementation of the code that I used is below. Please consider that I used a machine with 8 cores

```
def labelize_tweets_ug(tweets,label):
   result = []
   prefix = label
   for i, t in zip(tweets.index, tweets):
       result.append(TaggedDocument(t.split(), [prefix + '_%s' % i]))
   return result

# all_x is a list of tweets
all_x_w2v = labelize_tweets_ug(all_x, 'all')
cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()


model_ug_cbow = Word2Vec(sg=0, size=100, negative=5, window=2, min_count=2, 
workers=cores, alpha=0.065, min_alpha=0.065)
model_ug_cbow.build_vocab([x.words for x in tqdm(all_x_w2v)])

for epoch in range(30):
    model_ug_cbow.train(utils.shuffle([x.words for x in tqdm(all_x_w2v)]),total_examples=len(all_x_w2v), epochs=1)
    model_ug_cbow.alpha -= 0.002
    model_ug_cbow.min_alpha = model_ug_cbow.alpha
```

Comment: in part of training model, on train_model.train(doc_list), it will error, it needs arguments of total_examples=x.corpus_count, and epochs=x.epochs, when i applied x with train_model, which is corpus_count is 100000 and epochs is 5, it will run but very slow, and error in the middle of process. have you tried those code?

Comment: @thomidhia I edited my answer to reply to your comment.